# Android studio use camera to make a photo vs load photo from storage

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am working on an Android app functionality where I click a button and get the choice to make a photo with the camera or to load a photo from storage.
For making a photo I am using the command

```
myBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
```

For loading from storage I am using the comman

```
myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PATH);
```

Now I am trying the following: first I choose to make a photo and display it, then I choose from storage but I choose the photo I just made before and display it. In both cases I resize to 200x200 before displaying.

However the results look very different. Probably in one case nearest neighboor downsampling is used and in the other linear downsampling is used. However I don't find proper documentation.

How can I find out what downsampling is used and change it so that in both cases the same is used and the image displays looks the same?

Thank you.

P.S.: in case of decodeFile I found that options can be provided to the command however no idea which kind of options.

Comment: Your first code line obtains a bitmap of a thumbnail of the taken image. Not a full sized image. Adapt the camera intent to write full image to the uri you provide for it.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. What would be the command to do that? Alternatively can I use the same thumbnail for loading from storage? Also alternatively can I change the downsampling for the thumbnail?

Comment: Please ghoogle a bit as there are so many tutorials for the camera intent.